Accelerometer and Gyroscope sampling frequency
I have configured my accelerometer and gyroscope ODR for 200Hz and reading data from sensor every 100Hz/10msec from mcu.
I will be implementing LPF and HPF for above sensor data.
What will be the sampling frequency for this filter? Is it 100 or 200?

You answered your own question: you sample data at 100 Hz. That's the definition of sample rate (and I'll assume you have taken care of limiting the analog bandwidth of the signal you're sampling, though that is a different topic alltogether). So, it's not quite clear where your question "My sample rate is X. What is my sample rate?" arises from. Could you explain why you think it might be 200 Hz?

@MarcusMüller actually I am confused whether the sampling frequency for my lowpass filter will be the frequency (100hz) at which I am reading data from sensor or the sensor sampling frequency(odr=200hz).

again, the sampling frequency is 100 Hz. Where does your 200 Hz come from?

@MarcusMüller Thanks Noted. I have to measure roll angle using accelro and gyro. So, what could be general cutoff frequency I should consider for lowpass and high pass filter.

can't tell you, that depends on your sensor and what kind of mechanical system you're measuring. Fighter airplanes or vibration test platforms experience different bandwidths than passenger trains or electric scooters.
